# No matter which language I choose VS Code can only show English

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use "Configure Display Language" to change to another language and restart, then VS Code still tells me that English is the current language. I checked argv.json and the language has been changed there. I tried Japanese and French and they had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the VS Code settings to make sure the corresponding language extension has been installed and enabled.

Reference: [VS Code Display Language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales)